# Index of Array out of boundries though I never meant so

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote this simple code

```
int[] arr = new int[5];

System.out.printf("Please enter %d numbers: ", arr.length);
for (int i1=0; i1<arr.length; i1++) {
    arr[j] = S.nextInt();
}
System.out.printf("The numbers you enterd in reverse order are: ");
for (int i1=(arr.length); i1>=0; i1--) {
    System.out.print(arr[i1]);
}
```

And when I tried to print the array in reverse I got an error of  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

As I see it I never pointed to an Index which is bigger than 5. How could this be solved?

Comment: The reverse loop should start with `arr.length - 1`

Comment: Why do you use `j` as index in `arr[j] = S.nextInt();` inside loop based on `i1`? Since `j` doesn't change you are writing results of `nextInt()` into same location in array.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the array index must be between **0** and **length-1**. So you can do:

```
for (int i1=(arr.length - 1); i1>=0; i1--) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop should start with arr.length -1. Then it will work. In your reverse loop you are expecting 6 elements. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no element whose index is the same as the array length. When you count down, you have to go from `length-1` down to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum index of your array is 4 (0,1,2,3 and 4). In your seccond loop hou start with assigning the length of the array to i1, which is 5 and hence out of bounds. You should use the length - 1